# Auto Adjusting Video's with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Alright so what I am trying to do is have the Twitch Player and Chat auto adjust to patch the width and height of the page. Currently when you scroll down the page, if you browser isn't the right size the chat will appear under the player and just kinda break everything. Here is a link to a current copy of the website http://exudev.ca so you can kinda see what I am talking about.

Here is the HTML

```
  <div class ="twitch">
      <div class ="twitch-player">
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="600" width="1020" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=ifstudios" bgcolor="#000000"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="all" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" /><param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=ifstudios&auto_play=true&start_volume=10" /></object><a href="http://www.twitch.tv/ifstudios" style="padding:2px 0px 4px; display:block; width:345px; font-weight:normal; font-size:10px;text-decoration:underline; text-align:center;"></a>
      </div>
      <div class ="twitch-chat">
        <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://twitch.tv/ifstudios/chat?popout=" height="600" width="400"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the CSS

```
.twitch {
  background-color: #353535;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 800px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.twitch-player {
  float:left;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
  padding-top: 100px
}
.twitch-chat {
  float:right;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
  padding-top: 100px
}
```

Comment: can you add image for "kinda break everything" situation please :) ?

Answer (score 0):

Few things, first you'll want to determine what you want the chat to actually do when it gets to that particular size. The reason the problem is happening, is because of a "responsive" issue. You have floats on the two containers, .twitch-chat, and .twitch-player with static widths (being set by the iframes). So they will float to their respective sides until they both can't fit on the screen anymore. Once that happens, one of them will jump down to the next row, which I assume is the problem you're running into.

My suggestion, would be to do the following:

**html**

```
<div class="twitch clearfix">
    <div class="twitch-player"><object width="100%"></div>
    <div class="twitch-chat"><iframe width="100%"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.twitch {
    position: relative;
    max-width:1400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#353535;
    min-height:800px;
}

.twitch-player {
    float:left;
    width:80%;
    padding-left:20px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.twitch-chat {
    float:right;
    width:20%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: '\0020'; display: block; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden; width: 0; height: 0; clear: both; }

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .twitch-player, .twitch-chat {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

I didn't fully test this on your stuff, but it should make the following happen: 1) your video player and chat will be no more then 1400 pixels wide, centered on the screen, the video taking up 80%. 2) when the screen gets to be smaller then 800px (can change to what ever the correct point is) the chat and video will both take up 100% of the page, making the "drop" appear more natural.